# Anonymous vs Non Anonymous functions Lua

Tags: function, functional-programming, lua, anonymous-function

I am learning Lua and have come across the concept of anonymous functions. It's interesting but I was wondering what additional advantage it provides over non anonymous functions.

So If I have something like

```
function(a,b) return (a+b) end
```

The function is anonymous and if I have

```
function add(a,b) return (a+b) end
```

The function is non anonymous. The second is better because I can call it wherever I want and I also know what my function is doing. So what's the advantage of anonymous functions? Am I missing something here?

Comment: You got it backwards. A much more useful mental model is treating `function f(...) ... end` as syntactic sugar for `local f = function(...) ... end`, and think of functions in general as objects instead of static building blocks of your program. You don't ask why you can use number literals without giving them an elaborate english name first, do you?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To be honest, there is no such thing as a *named function* in Lua. All functions are actually anonymous, but can be stored in variables (which have a name).

The named *function* syntax `function add(a,b) return a+b end` is actually a [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for `add = function(a,b) return a+b end`.

Functions are often used as event handlers and for decisions which a library does not/cannot know, the most famous example being `table.sort()` - using your function, you can specify the sorting order:

```
people = {{name="John", age=20}, {name="Ann", age=25}}
table.sort(people, function (a,b) return a.name < b.name end)
```

The point is that most probably you won't need the function later. Of course, you can also save the function to a (possibly local) variable and use that:

```
local nameComparator = function (a,b) return a.name < b.name end
table.sort(people, nameComparator)
```

For more information, read this [section on functions in PiL](http://www.lua.org/pil/5.html).

Answer (score 5):

The second example is equivalent to
`add = function(a,b) return a+b end`
So really you're using anonymous functions all the time, in a trivial sense.

But anonymous functions can get much more useful in other contexts. For example, using functions to mutate other functions (the soul of functional programming.)

```
function make_version_with_n_args (func, n)
    if n == 1 then
        return function (x) return x end
    else
        return function (x, ...)
            return func (x, make_version_with_n_args (func, n-1)(...))
        end
    end
end

add_four = make_version_with_n_args (function (a, b) return a+b end, 4)

print (add_four(3, 3, 3, 3))

add_sizes = {}
for i = 1, 5 do 
    add_sizes[i] = make_version_with_n_args(function (a, b) return a+b end, i)
end

func_args = {}
for i = 1, 5 do
    func_args[#func_args+1] = 2
    print (add_sizes[i](unpack(func_args)))
end

function make_general_version (func)
    return function (...)
        local args = {...}
        local result = args[#args]
        for i = #args-1,1,-1 do
            result = func(args[i], result)
        end
        return result
    end
end

general_add = make_general_version (function (a, b) return a+b end)

print (general_add(4, 4, 4, 4))
```

Basically, you can create a name for every single function if you want to, but in situations where you are throwing around so many one-off functions, it is *more convenient not to do so*.